# ASP.NET API return part of object as json

Tags: asp.net, json, api, rest, controller

I am using ASP.NET API and I have an object I wish to return from the controller, so far I have been using `return Ok(item);`.

This will return all the properties of that item, however I want to return selected properties from it, like name and Date only instead of everything.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an anonymous type; that should work fine:

```
return Ok(new { name = item.Name, date = item.Date});
```

If not, you can simply create a class with the Name/Date properties; just like you return item and it gets serialized into a JSON object, anonymous and custom classes would also serialize OK.

Edit: if you have an inner collection, you can also generate a subset via:

```
new { 
      name = item.Name, 
      moreitems = item.subitems.Select(i => new { name = i.Name, etc })
}
```

OR, this is where creating a view model with a subset of properties may be beneficial, to make the process easier.

Comment: But what if I have item.MoreItems and want to remove a property from each one of them?

Comment: See my edit, you can use LINQ select, and get the fields you want.  There is no easy way to remove properties; essentially you have to recreate an objects with the properties you want...  you can use LINQ, or create a view model that only has the properties you want, and then build that up from the source.

Comment: Brilliant exactly what I wanted